# Unable to mount NFS remote share during bootup

Tags: 16.04, automount, nfs

I am trying to mount directory during boot up on Ubuntu 16.04. I followed the exact steps mentioned in this tutorial [link](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-nfs-mount-on-ubuntu-16-04#prerequisites). I was able to mount and umount the folders manually.

As mentioned in the tutorial i also made changes to /etc/fstab ,but unfortunately when i boot the system automatic mounting is failing.

Also tried manual mounting and both of them are working fine.

```
sudo mount -a
sudo start nfs-home.mount
```

/etc/fstab

```
nth@nthYOGA:~$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=3384679d-4d31-4617-b9e4-d4ba7f0d4334 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=CC87-B297  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=d18f6756-5068-4b1c-99f7-eeff16bf3edf none            swap    sw              0       0

XX.XX.XX.XX:/var/nfs/general    /nfs/general   nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
XX.XX.XX.XX:/home       /nfs/home      nfs auto,nofail,noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 0 0
```

Here are the logs

```
nth@nthYOGA:~$ systemctl status nfs-home.mount 
● nfs-home.mount - /nfs/home
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/fstab; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2018-05-10 20:49:24 CEST; 13min ago
    Where: /nfs/home
     What: XX.XX.XX.XX:/home
     Docs: man:fstab(5)
           man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
  Process: 1038 ExecMount=/bin/mount XX.XX.XX.XX:/home /nfs/home -t nfs -o noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 (code=exited, status=32)


nth@nthYOGA:~$ journalctl -u nfs-home.mount 
-- Logs begin at Thu 2018-05-10 20:49:22 CEST, end at Thu 2018-05-10 21:05:01 CEST. --
May 10 20:49:24 nthYOGA systemd[1]: Mounting /nfs/home...
May 10 20:49:24 nthYOGA mount[1038]: mount.nfs: Network is unreachable
May 10 20:49:24 nthYOGA systemd[1]: nfs-home.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
May 10 20:49:24 nthYOGA systemd[1]: Failed to mount /nfs/home.
May 10 20:49:24 nthYOGA systemd[1]: nfs-home.mount: Unit entered failed state.


systemctl show nfs-home.mount 
Where=/nfs/home
What=XX.XX.XX.XX:/home
Options=rw,noatime,vers=4.0,rsize=1048576,wsize=1048576,namlen=255,acregmin=1800,acregmax=1800,acdirmin=1800,acdirmax=1800,hard,proto=tcp,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.0.2,local_lock=none,addr=XX.XX.XX.XX
Type=nfs4
TimeoutUSec=1min 30s
ControlPID=0
DirectoryMode=0755
SloppyOptions=no
Result=success
ExecMount={ path=/bin/mount ; argv[]=/bin/mount XX.XX.XX.XX:/home /nfs/home -t nfs -o noatime,nolock,intr,tcp,actimeo=1800 ; ignore_errors=no ; start_time=[Thu 2018-05-10 21:15:06 CEST] ; stop_time=[Thu 2018-05-10 21:15:07 CEST] ; pid=2256 ; cod
Slice=system.slice
ControlGroup=/system.slice/nfs-home.mount
MemoryCurrent=18446744073709551615
CPUUsageNSec=18446744073709551615
TasksCurrent=18446744073709551615
Delegate=no
CPUAccounting=no
CPUShares=18446744073709551615
...
...
...
KillSignal=15
SendSIGKILL=yes
SendSIGHUP=no
Id=nfs-home.mount
Names=nfs-home.mount
Requires=-.mount system.slice
Wants=network-online.target
WantedBy=remote-fs.target
Conflicts=umount.target
Before=umount.target remote-fs.target
After=-.mount system.slice systemd-journald.socket network.target remote-fs-pre.target network-online.target
RequiresMountsFor=/nfs
Documentation=man:fstab(5) man:systemd-fstab-generator(8)
Description=/nfs/home
LoadState=loaded
ActiveState=active
SubState=mounted
FragmentPath=/run/systemd/generator/nfs-home.mount
SourcePath=/etc/fstab
....
....
```

Comment: Can you post your /etc/fstab?

Comment: Hi,  I have updated the description with fstabs file

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Fixed it by changing `auto` to `x-systemd.automount,noauto`
in `/etc/fstab`.

Example:

```
192.168.178.42:/disk1/data /media/data nfs nouser,rsize=32768,wsize=32768,atime,x-systemd.automount,noauto,rw,dev,noexec,suid 0 0
```

From [systemd.mount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.mount.html):

> `x-systemd.automount`
>
> An automount unit will be created for the file system. See [systemd.automount(5)](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.automount.html#) for details.